# What is the $C^1$ domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I just came across the Deuflhard & Bornemann text on Scientific Computing with ODEs where they write, for example:

> $f \in C(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$

In other places they use $C^1(\cdot,\cdot)$.

Easy question: what does the $C$ / $C^n$ refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is the set of all continuous functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. $\mathcal{C}^k(X,Y)$ is the set of all functions that have continuous $k$th derivative, with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$.

Comment: $C^1$ denotes continuously differentiable; $C$ denotes continuous; $C^k$ would be $k$ times continuously differentiable.

Comment: And $C^{\infty}$ denotes smooth.

Comment: Can somebody collect the content of all these comments into an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $C(X,Y)$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.
- $C^k(X,Y)$ is the set of all $k$ times continuously differentiable functions from $X$ to $Y$.
- $C^\infty(X,Y)$ is the set of all smooth functions from $X$ to $Y$.
- $C^\omega(X,Y)$ is the set of all analytic functions from $X$ to $Y$.

If $Y$ is omitted it *usually* means that it's $\mathbb R$, but in some contexts it can also be $\mathbb R^n$, $\mathbb C$ or even $\mathbb C^n$.